# How can I insert this part of the model in latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

How can i include this part of the the model in latex, i already tried tabular and allign but nothing results, I am little rookie in equations mode still.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As our community bot already suggested, it would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far. This will help us help you, since there are various ways to achieve this. Please edit the question using the "Edit" link to provide such additional information.

Comment: There are several ways to change the margins, such as a minipage or trivlist.  You might look at the amsthm and thmtools packages.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\textup{Maximize or Minimize}\quad z &= c_0+c_1x+\dotsb + c_nx_n\\
\text{subject to:}\hspace{43pt} & \\
& \hspace{-5pt}a_{i1}x_1 +a_{i2}x_2+\dotsb +a_{in}x_n \hspace{5pt} \begin{matrix}
 \leq\\ \geq \\ =    
\end{matrix}\hspace{20pt} i=1, \ldots , m \\
& \hspace{-5pt}x_j\,\biggl\{\begin{matrix}
 \geq\\ \gtrless     
\end{matrix}\hspace{138pt} j=1, \ldots , n.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{cll}
    \text{Maximize or Minimize} & z = c_0 + c_1x + \dots + c_nx_n\\
    \text{subject to:}\\
    & a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2}x_2 + \dots + a_{in}x_n
                         \begin{array}{c} \le\\ \ge\\ =\end{array} b_i
                                & i = 1, \dots, m\\
    & x_j\left\{\begin{array}{l} \ge 0\\ \gtrless 0\end{array}\right.
                                & j=1, \dots, m.
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]